# Is this definition of a function correct?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, quantifiers

So im trying to teach myself some logic and how quantifier scope and bound works and I saw the following defintion of a function which left me scratching my head.

$$\forall a\in A \exists b\in B:((a,b)\in R\land \forall b'\in B:(a,b')\in R\implies b=b').$$

We can see from the defintion that the variables $a$ and $b$ are bound in the entire expression by the brackets however my confusion arises for the variable $b'$ clearly it is bounded in the set $B$ however for the implication no brackets are used to bound $b'$ in the implication so basically my question is should we instead write

$$\forall a\in A \exists b\in B:((a,b)\in R\land \forall b'\in B:((a,b')\in R\implies b=b')).$$

With the addition of the extra brackets we have bounded the $b'$ in the implication as it falls within the quantifiers scope is this correct unnecessary or wrong?.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $$\forall\,a\in A:\exists!\,b\in B:(a,b)\in R.$$

Comment: The parenthesis are unnecessary precisely because the consequent $b=b'$ contains the quantified variable $b'$. Other interpretations would be meaningless.

Comment: I understand that $\exists$$!$ means exactly one but which of the formulas I gave is correct

Comment: @yves daoust but without the parentheses the variables will be free variables correct

Comment: "will be free variables correct": what ?

Comment: @yves daoust sorry I meant that if I didn't add the extra brackets in this part of the formula  $$\forall b'\in B:(a,b')\in R\implies b=b').$$ then wouldn't the $b'$ technically be considered free in the $b$=$b'$  part of the implication since it does not fall in the scope of the quantifer $\forall b'$

Comment: That would seem so unlikely !

Comment: @YvesDaoust careful! the formulae $\forall x \phi \to \psi$ and $\forall x (\phi \to \psi)$ are NOT equivalent. Homeschooler is correct.

Comment: @Simone: the question is about $\forall x\phi(x)\to\psi(x)$ and the possibility of the interpretation $(\forall x\phi(x))\to\psi(x)$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Indeed, and we all agree that the author intended it as $\forall x (\phi (x) \to \psi (x))$, but technically OP's version is the wff. A robot would regard the author's formulation as either not a wff or as ambiguous.

Comment: @Simone: I know and you know that I know and I know that you know that I know.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I wasn't insinuating anything, I apologize if it came across that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should we instead write
>
> $$\forall a\in A \exists b\in B:((a,b)\in R\land \forall b'\in B:((a,b')\in R\implies b=b')).$$

Yes.  You would use this to prove that the set of ordered pairs $R$ is a function mapping each element of $A$ to a unique element of $B$.

If you have established or simply assumed that $R$ is a function mapping each element of $A$ to a unique element of $B$, you could write

$$\forall a\in A: (R(a)\in B)$$

where $R(a)$ is the image of $a$ under $R$.

Comment: my question was which of the 2 definitions I gave was the correct one is there a difference between the two?

Comment: The original looks like a typo. Your version is correct. I added the rest about function notation because you will find it much easier to work with in proofs.

Comment: @DanChristensen It might even NOT be a typo, some authors are that careless with brackets: they rule out formulae with free variables and assume that context alone should clarify the ambiguity. And this Q shows this is not so.... all for the benefit of a few millimeters of ink saved.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that your version is actually better. In the context of the definition of functions, where the author is establishing the uniqueness of $R(a)$ using Russell's definite descriptions, one should understand the last quantifier to range over the whole following conditional, but as written it could be interpreted as ranging over the antecedent only, and leaving the consequent with a free variable.

Comment: I disagree with that, as logical formulas aren't meant to be interpreted (interpretation here in the psychological context, not the logical). Logical formulas are what they are, a syntactic object based on some grammar, and so as long as the formula abides to that grammar, it has an unambiguous meaning.

Comment: @iMrFelix I fail to see the relevance the point you just made, other than my use of the word "interpreted".

Comment: *of the point. Sorry.

Comment: I just wanted to emphasize that for two equivalent logical formula (they are equivalent), one cannot quantify that one is "better" than the other. Hence, writing "your version is actually better" is dangerous, as OP might interpret it in a sense that his version is "more correct" than the other.

Comment: @iMrFelix it depends on the system of logic OP is working with whether they are equivalent or not: if it doesn't allow for formulae with free variables then, in the context, $\forall x \, Fx \to Gx$ can be thought of as $\forall x ( Fx \to Gx)$, because otherwise it wouldn't be a wff, but it's an ambiguous construction. If it does allow for free variables then they're not equivalent! because   $\forall x \phi \to \psi$ is not equivalent to $\forall x (\phi \to \psi)$.